# Проверка диапазона вводимых значений

Tags: c++, c, структуры, проверка, scanf

Необходимо проверить диапазон вводимых, при помощи scanf, значений от 0 до 3 в поле структуры (перечисление). Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка?

```
printf_s("Ведите категорию: ");
scanf_s("%d", &a->category);
while (scanf_s("%d", &a->category) < 0 || scanf_s("%d", &a->category) > 3)
{
    printf("Неверное полученное значение, попробуйте еще: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a->category);
}
```

Comment: Подозреваю, в том, что Вы в условии цикла еще дважды читаете переменную, вместо того. чтобы просто ее проверить. Совет: читайте во вспомогательную переменную, проверяйте ее, при неудаче - читайте заново. При удаче - переписывайте в поле структуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> scanf_s: Возвращает число успешно преобразованных и назначенных полей.

т.е. вы неверно итерпритируете результат - проверять надо переменные. И коментатор выше прав, Вы зачем то лишний раз перед циклом читаете значение.

```
printf_s("Ведите категорию: ");
while(true){
   scanf_s("%d", &a->category);
   if (a->category < 0 || a->category > 3) {
      //можно зациклится :)
      printf_s("Неверное полученное значение, попробуйте еще: ");
   }
   else break;
}
```

Comment: Зачем читает перед циклом - понятно. Чтобы можно было проверить в условии цикла. А вот зачем в самом условии читает - и правда не понятно :)

Comment: Спасибо друзья !!!! Всё заработало!!!!